# Heroku compiles, but I still get Application Error

Tags: javascript, express, heroku

I have a [super simple express/node application](https://github.com/s1monb/html_css-ma1) to test out how to use Heroku. Here is my entire `app.js` file:

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
const port = '8080' || process.env.PORT;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`)
})
```

It compiles perfectly, but when I try to send a request to the site, I get an application error:

[image]

I run `git push heroku master` inside my project folder.
This is the response:

[image]

Everything seems to be working. In my `Procfile` I have

```
web: npm start
```

and in my `package.json` I have the script

```
"start": "node app.js"
```

When I try to connect

I get the error above. I run `heroku logs` and get this output:

```
λ heroku logs
2018-05-07T10:59:05.711233+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:11)
2018-05-07T10:59:05.711235+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:228:19)
2018-05-07T10:59:05.720402+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the html_css-ma1@1.0.0 start script.
2018-05-07T10:59:05.720552+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-05-07T10:59:05.807864+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-05-07T10:59:05.808109+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-05-07T10:59:05.808259+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-05-07T10_59_05_722Z-debug.log
2018-05-07T10:59:05.880130+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-05-07T10:59:05.902499+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-05-07T10:59:05.905620+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-05-07T10:59:08.281431+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-05-07T10:59:10.714118+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v10.0.0
2018-05-07T10:59:10.714580+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
2018-05-07T10:59:10.714828+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
2018-05-07T10:59:10.715125+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9.
2018-05-07T10:59:10.715364+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
2018-05-07T10:59:10.806649+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-05-07T10:59:10.806654+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2018-05-07T10:59:10.806652+00:00 app[web.1]: > html_css-ma1@1.0.0 start /app
2018-05-07T10:59:10.806656+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-05-07T10:59:11.229162+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:167
2018-05-07T10:59:11.229201+00:00 app[web.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2018-05-07T10:59:11.229203+00:00 app[web.1]:       ^
2018-05-07T10:59:11.229205+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-05-07T10:59:11.229207+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80
2018-05-07T10:59:11.229209+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1313:19)
2018-05-07T10:59:11.229212+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Server.listen (net.js:1466:7)
2018-05-07T10:59:11.229210+00:00 app[web.1]:     at listenInCluster (net.js:1378:12)
2018-05-07T10:59:11.229214+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.listen (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
2018-05-07T10:59:11.229215+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:10:5)
2018-05-07T10:59:11.229217+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
2018-05-07T10:59:11.229218+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
2018-05-07T10:59:11.229220+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
2018-05-07T10:59:11.229222+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
2018-05-07T10:59:11.229224+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
2018-05-07T10:59:11.229225+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event at:
2018-05-07T10:59:11.229227+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitErrorNT (net.js:1357:8)
2018-05-07T10:59:11.229228+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:174:19)
2018-05-07T10:59:11.229230+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:11)
2018-05-07T10:59:11.229232+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:228:19)
2018-05-07T10:59:11.229233+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:575:3)
2018-05-07T10:59:11.237647+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-05-07T10:59:11.238047+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2018-05-07T10:59:11.239658+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! html_css-ma1@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
2018-05-07T10:59:11.239812+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2018-05-07T10:59:11.240137+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2018-05-07T10:59:11.240341+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the html_css-ma1@1.0.0 start script.
2018-05-07T10:59:11.240579+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-05-07T10:59:11.250911+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-05-07T10:59:11.251110+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-05-07T10:59:11.251244+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-05-07T10_59_11_242Z-debug.log
2018-05-07T10:59:11.306925+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-05-07T10:59:11.321717+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-05-07T11:04:53.029487+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=stormy-garden-84636.herokuapp.com request_id=32bd2f98-0cec-4f5d-8755-94164154d506 fwd="109.247.251.198" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-07T11:04:53.667123+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stormy-garden-84636.herokuapp.com request_id=7864ed19-2cee-40d9-9c60-825963ddc827 fwd="109.247.251.198" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-07T11:49:12.389964+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-05-07T11:49:15.663542+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-05-07T11:49:18.056472+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v10.0.0
2018-05-07T11:49:18.057100+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
2018-05-07T11:49:18.057382+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
2018-05-07T11:49:18.057751+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9.
2018-05-07T11:49:18.058023+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
2018-05-07T11:49:18.165241+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-05-07T11:49:18.165244+00:00 app[web.1]: > html_css-ma1@1.0.0 start /app
2018-05-07T11:49:18.165246+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2018-05-07T11:49:18.165247+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-05-07T11:49:18.538620+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:10:5)
2018-05-07T11:49:18.538622+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
2018-05-07T11:49:18.538623+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
2018-05-07T11:49:18.538625+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
2018-05-07T11:49:18.538626+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
2018-05-07T11:49:18.538628+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
2018-05-07T11:49:18.538629+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event at:
2018-05-07T11:49:18.538631+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitErrorNT (net.js:1357:8)
2018-05-07T11:49:18.538632+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:174:19)
2018-05-07T11:49:18.538634+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:11)
2018-05-07T11:49:18.538635+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:228:19)
2018-05-07T11:49:18.538637+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:575:3)
2018-05-07T11:49:18.547708+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-05-07T11:49:18.538619+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.listen (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
2018-05-07T11:49:18.538609+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-05-07T11:49:18.538611+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80
2018-05-07T11:49:18.538615+00:00 app[web.1]:     at listenInCluster (net.js:1378:12)
2018-05-07T11:49:18.538616+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Server.listen (net.js:1466:7)
2018-05-07T11:49:18.547712+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2018-05-07T11:49:18.551362+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! html_css-ma1@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
2018-05-07T11:49:18.538583+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:167
2018-05-07T11:49:18.551365+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2018-05-07T11:49:18.551367+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2018-05-07T11:49:18.538605+00:00 app[web.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2018-05-07T11:49:18.538607+00:00 app[web.1]:       ^
2018-05-07T11:49:18.538613+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1313:19)
2018-05-07T11:49:18.577541+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-05-07T11:49:18.551369+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the html_css-ma1@1.0.0 start script.
2018-05-07T11:49:18.551374+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-05-07T11:49:18.578108+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-05-07T11_49_18_551Z-debug.log
2018-05-07T11:49:18.577866+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-05-07T11:49:18.674693+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-05-07T11:49:18.658509+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-05-07T12:04:35.580986+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=stormy-garden-84636.herokuapp.com request_id=667ed5c8-b4df-44b9-8eb8-eaac78fb0b95 fwd="109.247.251.198" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I'm not really sure what to do. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Error messages are made of _text_. They should be shared _as text_, not as screenshots. Text can be copied and pasted into a text editor! Screenshots cannot :-(. Text can be efficiently searched! Screenshots cannot :-(. Text can be consumed by users of assistive technologies, like screenreaders! Screenshots cannot :-(. Please give text the respect it deserves instead of banishing it to inaccessible image formats.

Comment: Just ask next time ;) 
`2018-05-07T12:04:35.580986+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=stormy-garden-84636.herokuapp.com request_id=667ed5c8-b4df-44b9-8eb8-eaac78fb0b95 fwd="109.247.251.198" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and replace the images with text instead of adding text in comments. The section of of `heroku logs` you're showing doesn't look very interesting—is there anything else?

Comment: @Chris Added the entire log now as text. Thanks for looking into this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining your `port` variable backwards:

```
const port = '8080' || process.env.PORT;
```

Since the literal `'8080'` is truthy, `port` will always be assigned `'8080'`.

The short-circuit behaviour of `||` is that it uses the first truthy value it finds, from left to right:

> ### Short-circuit evaluation
>
> As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:
>
> - `false && (anything)` is short-circuit evaluated to false.
> - `true || (anything)` is short-circuit evaluated to true.

Use

```
const port = process.env.PORT || '8080';
```

instead.